# Median of two sorted array

Tags: c++, algorithm, median

Here I have written code for  finding median of two sorted arrays:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define L  5
#define  M 6
 const int N=L+M;
int A[1000];//define 1 indexed aarray
int B[1000];
int max(int c,int d){
    return (c>=d)?c:d;

}
int min(int c,int d)
{
    return (c<=d)?c:d;
}

void  read(){
    cout<<" enter A array "<<endl;
    for (int i=1;i<=L;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter B array  "<<endl;
    for (int i=1;i<=M;i++)
        cin>>B[i];
    cout<<endl;


}
int median(int a[],int b[],int left,int right){
    if (left>right) {
        return median(b,a,max(1,(N/2)-L),min(M,N/2));
    }
    int i=int(left+right)/2;
    int j=int(N/2)+i;
    if((j==0 || a[i]>b[j]) && (j==M || a[i]<=b[j+1])){
        return a[i];
    }
    else
    {
        if((j==0 || a[i]>b[j])  &&(j!=M && a[i]>b[j+1]))
        return median(a,b,left,i-1);
    }


        return median(a,b,i+1,right);

}

int main(){




    return 0;
}
```

My question is  what could be left and right values? It is from introduction to algorithms, I just don't understand what are values of left and right variables? 
I have defined left and right as 1 and N and tested with following arrays:

```
3 5 7 9 11 13
1 2 4 8 10
```

Answer is 13, which is not correct sure, what is wrong?

Comment: please provide functioning code. You could call your `median` function with *any* values for `left` and `right`.

Comment: "i have wrote code" -> "what could be left and right values".  How did you write code where you don't know what the variables are for?  I guess you mean you tried to *copy* some code and don't understand it?

Comment: copy  yes but not copy past,here it is  http://www2.myoops.org/course_material/mit/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/30C68118-E436-4FE3-8C79-6BAFBB07D935/0/ps9sol.pdf  soluion of  this problem,here is not indicated left and right value

Comment: @dato: `left` and `right` are defined in your handout: "The invariant is that the median is always in either `A[left..right]` or `B`". It gives their initial values as `max(1,N/2−M)` and `min(L,N/2)`.

Comment: so in main part,use these values?

Comment: please stop someone  downvoting,if can help me and if not,give others chance to explain me something,i never downvote nobody,never in  my life,in spite of her/his question,so please stop it!

Comment: Regarding your incorrect answer: there are a few places where you need to take care that you're getting the ceiling or floor values correctly - in C/C++, integer division on non-negative numbers will evaluate to the floor. You'll need to do a little extra work when you want the ceiling. You also have a typo for the line of code that corresponds to line 4 from the algorithm: you're adding where there should be a subtraction.  Finally, I think the biggest problem your code has is that when the arrays are swapped (when `left > right`), you need to also swap the array sizes `L` and `M` somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [homework problem you cited in a comment](http://www2.myoops.org/course_material/mit/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/30C68118-E436-4FE3-8C79-6BAFBB07D935/0/ps9sol.pdf) has what looks to be a pretty good explanation of `left` and `right`, including the starting values for them:

> Let the default values for left and right be such that calling
>   MEDIAN-SEARCH(A,B)  is equivalent to
>
> ```
> MEDIAN-SEARCH(A[1 ..l],B[1 ..m],max(1,ceil(n/2) - m),min(l,ceil(n/2)))
> ```
>
> The invariant in `MEDIAN-SEARCH(A,B)` is that the median is always in
>   either `A[left ..right]`  or `B`. This is true for the initial call because
>   `A` and `B` are sorted, so by the definition  of median it must be between
>   `max(1,ceil(n/2) - m)` and `min(l,ceil(n/2))`, inclusive. It is  also true
>   the recursive calls on lines 8 and 9, since the algorithm only
>   eliminates parts  of the array that cannot be the median by the
>   definition of median. The recursive call  on line 2 also preserves the
>   invariant since if `left > right` the median must be in `B` be­tween the
>   new `left` and `right` values.

If you work through the algorithm on paper with small arrays, it should become more clear what's going on. The algorithm converges in only a few steps if your arrays are smaller than a total of say 16 elements, so it should be quite workable on paper.

Comment: my array are  totally 11 elements

Comment: how to call  my median  function  in main part()?by which values?

Comment: Going by what the above problem stated would be the defaults for `left` and `right`, I think it should be: `median(a,b,max(1,((N+1)/2)-M),min(L,(N+1)/2))`.  Note that I used `(N+1)` in a couple spots instead of just `N` because of the way that C performs integer division this will result in the ceiling of `(N/2)`, which is what the algorithm calls for. You may need to make similar adjustments in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider the following

```
std::cout << "enter all number separated by a space ending with 'q'" 
          << std::endl;
std::vector<int> v(
    (std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)),
     std::istream_iterator<int>());

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
std::cout << "median value is: " 
          << std::advance(v.begin(), v.size()/2); 
          << std::endl;
```

Comment: but it is different ,i  am  trying to understand code itself,thanks but it is better   solution of my code

Comment: @dato; sorry i didn't mean to cut you short, and understand whats going on is important.

Comment: thanks  for helping  ,just i mean   to define what is  values left and right

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for finding the median of two sorted arrays of unequal length using the merge method of mergesort

```
package FindMedianBetween2SortedArrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UsingMergeMethodOfMergeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the first SORTED array");
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int[] array1 = new int[n];
            System.out.println("Enter the elements of the first SORTED array");
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                array1[i]=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the second SORTED array");
            int m = in.nextInt();
            int[] array2 = new int[m];
            System.out.println("Enter the elements of the second SORTED array");
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                array2[i]=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Median of the two SORTED arrays is: "+findMedianUsingMergeOfMergeSort(array1,array2));
        }
        finally{
            in.close();
        }
    }
    private static int findMedianUsingMergeOfMergeSort(int[] a, int[] b) {

    /*  a1 array and a2 array can be of different lengths.
        For Example:
      1.
        a1.length = 3
        a2.length = 6
        totalElements = 3+6=9 (odd number)
      2.
        a1.length = 4
        a2.length = 4
        totalElements = 4+4=8 (even number)
    */
        int totalElements = a.length+b.length;  // totalElements is the addition of the individual array lengths
        int currentMedian = 0;
        int prevMedian = 0;
        int i=0; // Index for traversing array1
        int j=0; // Index for traversing array2
        for(int k=0;k<totalElements;k++){    // k is index for traversing the totalElements of array1 and array2


        /*NOTE: In this entire for loop, the "if", "else" and "else if" is VERY IMP. DONOT interchange among them*/

            // if array1 is exhausted
            if(i==a.length)
                currentMedian=b[j++]; // elements of the second array would be considered


            // if array2 is exhausted
            else if(j==b.length)
                currentMedian=a[i++]; // elements of the first array would be considered

            else if(a[i]<b[j])
                currentMedian=a[i++];

            else //(b[j]<=a[i])            // this condition is ONLY "else" and not "if" OR "else if"
                currentMedian=b[j++];

            if(k==totalElements/2) // we reached the middle of the totalElements where the median of the combined arrays is found
                break;                 

            prevMedian = currentMedian;

        }

        // if the totalElements are odd
        if(totalElements%2!=0)
            return currentMedian;
        else
            return (prevMedian+currentMedian)/2;
    }
}
/*
Analysis:
    Time Complexity = Linear Time, O((m+n)/2)
    Space Complexity = O(1)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public:
    double findMedianSortedArrays(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        double median;
        for(int i = 0; i<nums2.size();++i){
            nums1.push_back(nums2[i]);
        };
        sort(nums1.begin(),nums1.end());
        if(nums1.size()%2 == 0){
            median = (double)(nums1[(nums1.size()/2)-1] + nums1[nums1.size()/2])/2;
            
        }else{
            if(nums1.size() == 1) median = nums1[0];
            median = nums1[((nums1.size()/2) + (nums1.size()%2)) - 1];
        }
        return median;
        
};
};
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.